# How would you go about normalizing/cleaning Salesforce data?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-cleaning, normalize

Our database has a Salesforce table called `LEAD` and the `JOB TITLE` column values need to be cleaned/normalized. There are several job titles that are the same but have different spelling, spaces and punctuation. For example, `sr analyst`, `senior analyst`, `sr   analyst`, `sr.  analyst`. There's about 250,000 rows of different titles--any ideas on how to approach this? This is all in a Snowflake data warehouse.

Comment: Two general approaches would be to update all variations to one standard, or, create a new table that maps all variations to one standard (and then queries would refer to this mapping table).  Both approaches will require some creativity in finding the variations and maintaining the data.  It's likely to be a rather manual task and it's a very common problem for CRM applications (and perhaps you can find other approaches by researching CRM data cleansing / management)

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about it:

(Note - ideally fix at the source by not allowing free text entry and forcing a selection, but if that's not possible, the following steps can be employed):

1. Create a mapping table of all the job title variants (VARIANT_JOB_TITLES) in one column (e.g. 'Senior Analyst', 'Sr. Analyst', 'Sr Analyst', etc) and the target standardized (STANDARD_JOB_TITLE) value (e.g. 'Senior Analyst').  Note that you will need to maintain this and add new variants / fat fingered typos that exist in the source system.

Job_Title_Map table:

```
VARIANT_JOB_TITLE    STANDARD_JOB_TITLE
Senior Analyst       Senior Analyst
Sr. Analyst          Senior Analyst
Sr Analyst           Senior Analyst
SA                   Senior Analyst
```

2. Add a nullable column to your snowflake contact table to contain the standardized title (STANDARD_JOB_TITLE).  This way you preserve the original title, and have the standardized version in your table for reporting.

Contact Table:

```
Lead      Job_Title     STANDARD_JOB_TITLE
John Doe  Sr. Analyst   NULL
Bob Doe   SA            NULL
Jane Doe  Sr Analyst    NULL
```

3. This is where the regular expression functions are your friend.  For each case where the STANDARD_JOB_TITLE is null in your contact table, use the REGEXP_REPLACE to take the source JOB_TITLE value - strip the leading and trailing spaces, and replace all remaining contiguous multiple spaces with a single space.  Perform an UPPER() on this processed job title, and do a join on UPPER() to the variant mapping table, returning the STANDARD_JOB_TITLE which you store in the the column STANDARD_JOB_TITLE located in the contact table.

Query:

```
update
    CONTACT C
set
    standard_job_title = jtm.standard_job_title
from
    job_title_map jtm
where
    c.standard_job_title is NULL 
    AND upper(
        trim(regexp_replace(c.job_title, '((\\ )+)+', ' '))
    ) = upper(trim(jtm.variant_job_title));
```

4. Rinse and repeat (adding new variants with their standard job title to your mapping table) until you have no null values in the STANDARD_JOB_TITLE column in your contact table.

Results:

Contact Table:

```
Lead      Job_Title     STANDARD_JOB_TITLE
John Doe  Sr. Analyst   Senior Analyst
Bob Doe   SA            Senior Analyst
Jane Doe  Sr Analyst    Senior Analyst
```